# Google Chrome Extension - Getting data from website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm designing my Google Chrome extension to store a variable created in a completely different website, which means I need to pass the variable over.

This is the code in the script.js of the website:

```
var editorExtensionId = "extension";

'use strict';
function x(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({n:1});
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(loginKey){
    console.log(loginKey.n);
});
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        function: x
    });
});
```

In the console log, however, it gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addListener')
at script.js:68:26"

I was wondering how to fix this.

Comment: _"This is the code in the script.js of the website"_ `chrome.runtime.onMessage` & `chrome.action.onClicked` are only available from your extension. You won't be able to use these from the website!

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. How should I send the variable over to the extension then?

Comment: Sorry, not that familiar with Chrome Extensions.

Comment: `chrome.action` can be used only in the background script, not in the content script.

Answer (score 1):

Your extension works on a website but you want some data from another website?

- Firstly, add permission storage for your manifest.json file to enable Chrome local storage.
- Then use "Document.querySelector()" or "Document.getElementById()" to take whatever data you need from website 2, write it into chrome storage by "chrome.storage.local.set"
- Finally at website 1, retrieve the variable you stored by "chrome.storage.local.get"